# Pass options array to jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am trying to avoid having to write the optinos array for each call to the plugin and I was wondering how can create one only shared options array to avoid this.

This could be applied to this call, for example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": ">"
      }
    }
  } );
} );
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$.dataTable.defaults = {
    "oLanguage": {
        "oPaginate": {
              "sNext": ">"
        }
     }
}
```

You can find more about the options array Im trying to modify in here:
http://datatables.net/usage/i18n

Comment: Where's the definition of `$.fn.dataTable()` ?

Comment: dataTable is a jQuery Plugin.

Comment: How did you try to use `$.dataTable.defaults`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the object first, and  you can pass it in at anytime you call the plugin.

```
var pluginDefaults = { 
    "oLanguage": {
        "oPaginate": { 
            "sNext": ">" 
        }
    }
};
```

And when ready to call the plugin, use it like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( pluginDefaults );
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I already tried it this way. Here you can find more about the plugin and the array options im trying to modify: http://datatables.net/usage/i18n

Comment: @Steve Can you show your attempt at doing it this way? There shouldn't be a problem with this.

Comment: Truth. I was using the options array in the PHP way, with $. Solved. I will accept your answer in 8 mins :)

Comment: +1, though the answer should include a snippet of how you would pass the default options to the plugin.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for adding the example useage :) Just realized I forgot to write that!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS No problem. We knew how to use it, just nice for the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "oLanguage": {
       "oPaginate": { 
          "sNext": ">" 
        }
    }
});
```

This will set the default datatables option, then you won't have to pass in the option over and over again

[Documenation](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/defaults.html)

Comment: Nice find. Definitely what the OP was attempting to do but didn't work, and makes most sense anyways!